# Plotmath expression with mathematical operators in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I am still struggling with correct labels of my plots. 
I managed to get this to work.

```
df <-data.frame(a=seq(1,20),b=seq(1,20))
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(paste(CH[4]~" formation rate"~"(",mu, mol, day^{-1},")")))
```

What it is missing is the operator sign " * " between mumol and day^-1. It should look like this: [image]
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `CH[4]~" formation rate"~"(",mu, mol%*%day^{-1},")"` not what you're looking for?

Comment: thank you for your input. Your snippet produces: http://imgur.com/41mtmwZ Definitely progress, but not quite there.

Comment: is this what you need `ylab(expression(CH[4]~formation~rate~(mu*mol~'*'~day^{-1})))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer not to use the `paste` style for expressions but to use `~` and `*` to separate terms with or without a space respectively. If you want an *, put it in quotes.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ylab(expression(CH[4]~formation~rate~(mu*mol~'*'~day^{-1})))
```